# Horizontal scrolling content with non-scrolling sidebar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a horizontal scrolling area with a sidebar, that is not scrollable. I want to create it without using `position: fixed;` but I can't make it work. What am I missing?

HTML

```
<div class="sidebar">
     <h1 class="logo">Title</h1>
</div>

<div class="scroll-area">
   <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
     Animi  harum, magnam, ducimus corporis ipsam blanditiis possimus
     voluptate obcaecati laboriosam dicta quidem perspiciatis ipsa
     tenetur. Asperiores veritatis dicta doloremque. Ea, ad.
   </p>

   <div class="image-gallery">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x800"></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x800"></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x800"></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.scroll-area {
  width: 3000px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

EDIT

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbnz808v/1/) to visualize my issue. As it is now, the sidebar is scrolling together with the content.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that achieves what I believe you're trying to do. Replace code as needed.

HTML:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch Report</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
            </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> Annuities Report</h4>

        </div>  
        <pre class="report-pre modal-body report-modal-body">
                                INDIVIDUAL ANNUITIES
                                                                                                                                                      BY AGENCY WITH AGENT DETAIL
                                                                                                                                                        COMMISSIONABLE DEPOSITS
                                                                                                                                                             MONTH TO DATE

AGENCY NUMBER    
AGENCY NAME                         FLEXIBLE ANNUITY                                                    SPIA                                                    SPDA                                                      VARIABLE ANNUITY                                                           TOTAL
 AGENT #         
 AGENT NAME COUNT    1ST YEAR   EXTERNAL   INTERNAL    SUBSEQUENT       TOTAL   COUNT    1ST YEAR   EXTERNAL   INTERNAL          TOTAL   COUNT    1ST YEAR   EXTERNAL   INTERNAL          TOTAL   COUNT    1ST YEAR   EXTERNAL   INTERNAL    SUBSEQUENT       TOTAL    COUNT   1ST YEAR   EXTERNAL   INTERNAL    SUBSEQUENT       TOTAL
            -----------------------------------------------------------------   ------------------------------------------------------   ------------------------------------------------------   -----------------------------------------------------------------    ----------------------------------------------------------------

EN00000006       
POE - James       
 AG00000001      
 POE, Henry 1.00       2,512     25,812          0        450         28,775     .00           0          0          0              0     .00           0          0          0              0     .00           0          0          0      1,741          1,741     1.00      2,512     25,812          0      2,191         30,516
 AG00050001      
 Eve,       .00           0          0          0          0              0     .00           0          0          0              0     .00           0          0          0              0     .00          52          0          0      3,081          3,133      .00         52          0          0      3,081          3,133
 AG000400      
 Bob,    .00          30          0          0        100            130     .00           0          0          0              0     .00           0          0          0              0     .00         166          0          0        370            536      .00        196          0          0        470            666

             1.00       2,542     25,812          0        550         28,905     .00           0          0          0              0     .00           0          0          0              0     .00         218          0          0      5,192          5,410     1.00      2,760     25,812          0      5,742         34,315
EN00000010       
LOST AGENT       
 AG00005      
 Jim, RI   .00           0          0          0          0              0     .00           0          0          0              0     .00           0          0          0              0     .00           0          0          0        100            100      .00          0          0          0        100            100

              .00           0          0          0          0              0     .00           0          0          0              0     .00           0          0          0              0     .00           0          0          0        100            100      .00          0          0          0        100            100


            </pre>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.report-modal-body {
    max-height:calc(100vh - 150px);
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:auto;
}
.report-pre {
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:auto;
    word-wrap:normal;
    margin:1px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheth/YE9Sx/8/)

Comment: I understand that. What I want to achieve is to have a sidebar to the left that is not scrollable, and a scrollable area to the right of the sidebar, which is scrollable horizontal.

Comment: I've added a fiddle that maybe makes it a bit easier to understand what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

**Full code:**

```css
.scroll-area {
  width: 85%;
  float: left;
  overflow: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
}
```

I hope this will help you.
Here is **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qxqkfx7/)**